# React ChartJS, Blank White Screen (No Error)

Tags: reactjs, api, chart.js, alpha-vantage

I am attempting to display the daily returns of SPY in a react page and displaying it on a ChartJS graph. I am using chart JS and an API call from Alphavantage. I am using the following code. I receive no errors but a blank white screen is all I see.

I have inputted my API key.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Chart } from "chart.js";

const SPYChart = () => {
  const [chartData, setChartData] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchSPYData = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(
        "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED&symbol=SPY&outputsize=compact&apikey=<My Api has been inserted>"
      );
      const data = await response.json();
      const dailyReturns = calculateDailyReturns(data["Time Series (Daily)"]);
      const labels = Object.keys(dailyReturns);
      const values = Object.values(dailyReturns);
      setChartData({
        labels: labels,
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "Daily Percentage Returns of SPY",
            data: values,
            borderColor: "#3e95cd",
            fill: false,
          },
        ],
      });
    };

    const calculateDailyReturns = (data) => {
      const closePrices = Object.values(data).map((item) =>
        parseFloat(item["4. close"])
      );
      const dailyReturns = {};
      for (let i = 1; i < closePrices.length; i++) {
        const todayReturn =
          (closePrices[i] - closePrices[i - 1]) / closePrices[i - 1];
        dailyReturns[Object.keys(data)[i]] = todayReturn;
      }
      return dailyReturns;
    };

    fetchSPYData();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const ctx = document.getElementById("SPYChart");
    new Chart(ctx, {
      type: "line",
      data: chartData,
      options: {
        responsive: true,
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: "Daily Percentage Returns of SPY",
        },
        scales: {
          xAxes: [
            {
              type: "time",
              time: {
                unit: "day",
                displayFormats: {
                  day: "MMM D",
                },
              },
              ticks: {
                maxTicksLimit: 10,
              },
            },
          ],
          yAxes: [
            {
              ticks: {
                callback: function (value, index, values) {
                  return (value * 100).toFixed(2) + "%";
                },
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    });
  }, [chartData]);

  return (
    <div>
      <canvas id="SPYChart" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SPYChart;
```

I attempted inputting basic boilerplate line chart Chart JS code that has worked. So I know the problem is with this code here and not with the rest of the react application. When I comment out this code I get the display I am expecting (minus the graph).

Comment: You could try to style the div's `height` and `width`; in my experience the canvas height and width attributes are not honored. But if it were just 100px are you sure you haven't missed it in the output page :) ? If it doesn't help, I'd recommend you replace the api fetch with a sample response so we could replicate and debug your code.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing some important points.

1. I don't know the version of chart.js that you use. But at v4, you need to register registerables:

```
    import { Chart, registerables } from "chart.js";
    ...
    Chart.register(...registerables);
    ...
```

2. In `react` we use `ref` to access canvas element:

```
import { useRef } from react;

function MyChart() {
  const [canvasElRef, setCanvasElRef] = useRef(null)

  ...

  return (
    <canvas ref={canvasElRef} />
  )
}
```

3. chart.js canvas element need a wrapper, and the canvas element must have an initial dimension for maintaining the responsive size (don't forget the `maintainAspectRatio: false` in the chart options.

```
function MyChart() {
  ...  
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      ...
    }
  ...

  return (
    <div style={{ width: "100vw", height: "100vh" }}>  <--- use your own styling
      <canvas ref={canvasElRef} width="600" height="350" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

4. You need to make sure that the data and canvas element are available before create `Chart` instance. Here you have to keep the instance at a `ref` so we can use it as reference for destroying the chart instance when unmount/cleanup process took place

```
  const [chartRef, setChartRef] = useRef(null)

  ...

  useEffect(() => {
    if (chartData && canvasElRef.current) {
      chartRef.current = new Chart(canvasElRef.current, {

      }
    }

    return () => {
      if (chartRef.current) {
        chartRef.current.destroy();
        chartRef.current = null;
      }
    }
  }
```

5. In v4, the title now is a part of `plugins`:

```
  options: {
    ...
    plugins: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: "Daily Percentage Returns of SPY",
      },
    },
  }
```

6. Chartjs moment adapter is the most important thing when using a time series chart. So you need to import it after importing `chart.js`

```
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import { ChartData, Chart, registerables } from "chart.js";
import "chartjs-adapter-moment";  <---- import here

Chart.register(...registerables);
```

And finaly, you can check the final code [here](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/thirsty-kare-51kx7b?selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A1%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A62%2C%22startColumn%22%3A1%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A62%7D%5D&file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx)